# Concat with conditional inner concat

Tags: mysql, concatenation, concat-ws

I am selecting with concat from a table with `Name` and `Notes` fields. I am putting the notes in open and close parentheses. In the cases where the `Notes` field is NULL I don't want any `()` as the first Select does:

`Select concat(Name,(concat(' (',Notes,')'))) from Table`

which gives me:

- Name1 (Notes1)
- Name2 ()

I tried `concat_ws`

`Select concat(Name,(concat_ws('(',Notes,')'))) from Table`

but this gives me

- Name1Notes1()
- Name2)

And `ifnull` didn't work at all.

I'd prefer to not do this with `Case/Then` because I have many tables I am `concatenating` using `left join` and it would make an already complex query unwieldy.

Comment: show also your expected  result

Comment: **Select concat(Name,IF(Notes is NULL , NULL, concat(' (',Notes,')'))) from Table;** does not work ?

Comment: @BernBuffen No it gets me closer but still `Name1 (Notes1)` and `Name 2 ()`

Comment: @user3649739 - Then check this please **Select concat(Name,IF(LENGTH(Notes) <1, NULL, concat(' (',Notes,')'))) from Table;**

Comment: @BernBuffen That returns `Name 1 (Notes1)` `NULL`

Comment: @BerndBuffen Ok my bad; there were some records where Notes was Empty vs NULL. I fixed that and it works fine.